# Display a summary of form element values before submit

Tags: jquery

Using jquery formtowizard.js with an ajax submit. I want the last step of the form to display a summary of all form fields that were filled out. I can get it to work in isolated test cases, but not in full use.
Form

```
<form id="Commission" method="post" action="PHP/CommissionsSubmit.php">
    <fieldset id="Initial">
        <legend>Enter Your Information</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="FName">First Name*</label><input type="text" name="FName" id="FName">
            </li>
         //repeat many li's
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Second Step</legend>
    //more li's
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Confirmation</legend>
    <span id="CFName"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

the jquery to get "#CFName" value

```
$('#FName').keyup(function() {
   $('#CFName').val($(this).val());
});
```

I can't get the value to appear in the span "#CFName"... Could this have to do with the "serialize" function or anything going on with my $ajax submit function? its happening before submit... Please help!

I apologize, but I've gone back and forth with "#CFName" being a span and an input, using .val and .html respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:   `$('#CFName').text($(this).val());`

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea.

You should use `.text()` otherwise

Comment: did not try .text - tired and overlooked it in favor of .val and .html, thank you!

Comment: .text should work the same as .html in most cases so if you tried .html and it didn't work then .val probably isn't the real issue.

Comment: Did you try loganphp's answer? His jsfiddle seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Got yours to work, could not get his to work with mutliple span's being populated from other inputs.

Comment: On a related question, how would you go about the final format being as such "First Name: (value from input)" I tried $('#Email').keyup(function(){
        $('#CEmail').text('Email' + $(this).val());
      });

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

```
$("#FName").keyup(function(){
                $('#CFName').html($('#Commission').serialize());
    });
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/KG7cN/

Comment: you mean multiple form elements??